# multi If else if statments

Tags: java, if-statement, stringbuffer

Hello I was playing around with StringBuffer and StringBuilder and this is a little program I wrote to help me understand how it work. However something strange came up not related to Stringbuffer but my multi if else if statement within my for loop.

My little code:

```
public class c
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    StringBuffer infixB = new StringBuffer();

    String infix = "3/8";

    for(int i = 0; i < infix.length(); i++)
    {
        infixB.append(infix.charAt(i));
    }

    infixB.append(')');

    System.out.println("Your current infix expression: "+infixB.toString());

    //go through the 'infixB' 1 position at a time
    for(int i = 0; i < infixB.length(); i++)
    {
        if(infixB.charAt(i) == '3')
        {
            System.out.println("Digit 3 at: " +i);
        }
        else if(infixB.charAt(i) == '/')
        {
            System.out.println("Operator at: "+i);
        }
        else if(infixB.charAt(i) == '8')
        {
            System.out.println("Digit 8 at: "+i);
        }
        else if(infixB.charAt(i) == ')');
        {
            System.out.println(") found at: " +i);
        }
    }

}
}
```

the expected output would be something like:

```
Your current infix expression: 3/8)
Digit 3 at: 0
Operator at: 1
Digit 8 at: 2
) found at: 3
```

However the world is not perfectly round so my output came out:

```
Your current infix expression: 3/8)
Digit 3 at: 0
) found at: 0
Operator at: 1
) found at: 1
Digit 8 at: 2
) found at: 2
) found at: 3
```

As you can see, for some reason within my for loop the last else if statement was executing EVEN AFTER a previous if or else if statement has already been executed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a semicolon at the end of your last condition.  Java will treat that semicolon as the body of your condition, and always execute the block in braces as an unrelated block.  Change

```
else if(infixB.charAt(i) == ')');
```

to

```
else if(infixB.charAt(i) == ')')
```

Comment: +1. I would also suggest to use the `switch-case` for that purpose

Comment: You were faster this time. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  System.out.println(") found at: " +i);
 }
```

this code is with no if condition so it is displaying every time with for loop condition